# mysql container won't start on kubernetes when backed by NFS Dynamic provisioner

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

I'm having issues getting the mysql container starting properly. But to sum it up, with the nfs dynamic provisioner the mysql container won't start and throws an error of `mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/mysql/': File exists` even though the NFS mount is in the container, and appears to be functioning properly.

I installed Dyanamic NFS provisioner installed on my K8 cluster from here https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/tree/master/nfs-client. The test claim and test pod they show on the instructions work.

Now to run mysql, I took the code snippets from here:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-single-instance-stateful-application/

`kubectl apply mysql-pvc.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: managed-nfs-storage  <--- THIS MATCHES MY NFS STORAGECLASS
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
```

`kubectl apply -f mysql-deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
  clusterIP: None
---
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mysql:5.6
        name: mysql
        env:
          # Use secret in real usage
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: password
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pv-claim
```

```
kubectl get pv,pvc
NAME                                                        CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                          STORAGECLASS          REASON   AGE
persistentvolume/mysql-pv-volume                            20Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound    default/mysql-pv-claim         managed-nfs-storage            5m16s

NAMESPACE      NAME                                    STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS          AGE
default        persistentvolumeclaim/mysql-pv-claim    Bound    mysql-pv-volume                            20Gi       RWO            managed-nfs-storage   5m27s
```

The pv was created automatically by the dynamic provisioner

Get the error...

```
$ kubectl logs mysql-7d7fdd478f-l2m8h
2020-03-05 18:26:21+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.6.47-1debian9 started.
2020-03-05 18:26:21+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-03-05 18:26:21+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 5.6.47-1debian9 started.
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/mysql/': File exists
```

This error stops the container from starting...

I went and deleted the deployment and added  `command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "sleep 100000" ]` so the container would start...

After getting into the container, I checked the NFS mount is properly mounted and is writable...

```
# df -h | grep mysql
nfs1.example.com:/k8/default-mysql-pv-claim-pvc-0808d1bd-69ca-4ff5-825a-b846b1133e3a  1.0T  1.6G 1023G   1% /var/lib/mysql
```

If I create a "local" pv

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
```

and created the mysql deployment, the mysql pod starts up without issue.

So at this point, with dynamic provisioning (potentially just on NFS?) the mysql container doesn't work.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what is the cause of this so here is few options.

First you could try setting [`securityContext`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/), because volume might be mounted without proper permissions.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: security-context-demo
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1000
    runAsGroup: 3000
    fsGroup: 2000
  volumes:
  - name: sec-ctx-vol
    emptyDir: {}
  containers:
  - name: sec-ctx-demo
    image: busybox
    command: [ "sh", "-c", "sleep 1h" ]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: sec-ctx-vol
      mountPath: /data/demo
    securityContext:
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
```

You can find out the proper group id and user by typing `id` and `gid` inside the container.
Or just using `kubectl exec -it <pod-name> bash`.

Second, try using [`subPath`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath)

```
volumeMounts:
- name: mysql-persistent-storage
  mountPath: "/var/lib/mysql"
  subPath: mysql
```

If that won't work I would test the NFS on another pod with `initContainer` that is creating a directory.
And I would redo the whole nfs maybe using [this guide](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/volumes/nfs).

Comment: Thanks. I checked the gid/uid and id: `uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)`, the gid = 0. I tried doing the subPath as well, but no dice.

I don't quite understand what the `initContainer` is. Where is that at? Is that in the container or the pod pod creation?

Comment: @KevinVasko, [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) is a link for docs regarding `initContainers`.

Comment: thanks. I created an initContainer that mounted the drive and wrote a test file to the folder. The main mysql container had the same error even though the initContainer had no problems with it. I don't think this has _anything_ to do with the NFS, provisioning. I think its something to do with the mysql container but I can't find it.

Comment: I don't think mysql container is running as root but as mysql user. Try changing permissions to allow that user.

Comment: See the solution here. https://github.com/kubeflow/kubeflow/issues/4827#issuecomment-598803422 It was basically NFS provisioner automatically picking the highest security context for the NFS share instead of `sec=sys` like I was expecting.